# Multiple 'Get items'

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Is it possible to have two 'Get items' in the same Flow?

I have created a Flow with a 'Get items' from a List of qualifications; I can see all (most) of the fields in the qualifications List.

I then created another 'Get items' from a List of members; however, I am not given access to any of the MemberList fields to filter.

Can you have to 'Get items' in the same Flow? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In a flow, you can have multiple `Get Items` action to retrieve list items data from SharePoint lists.

> I then created another 'Get items' from a List of members; however, I
> am not given access to any of the MemberList fields to filter.

Does your account have right permission to view list items? Would kind of error do you encounter? If possible, would you like to provide a screenshot of the detailed error message of that flow?